# django-embed-video - how to use Vimeo options

Tags: django, vimeo, embedding, video-embedding

I would like to embed Vimeo video to my website and I'd love to use some of options, that Vimeo provides, like color, autoplay etc.

Is there any chance to do it with [django-embed-video](https://github.com/yetty/django-embed-video)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But you have to build your own HTML. Just copy HTML from Vimeo page with your chosen options and replace video URL with `{{ my_video.url }}`. So it can look like that:

```
{% video item.video as my_video %}
  <iframe 
    src="{{ my_video.url }}?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ff0179&amp;autoplay=1" 
    width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" 
    webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen>
  </iframe>
{% endvideo %}
```